# How to delete cookie in IE webdriver C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to delete the cookies in the IE32 and IE64 bit webdriver , i have tried using following command

```
WebDriver.Cookies.DeleteCookieNamed("cookie name");
WebDriver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```

both of the option about is not deleting the cookies , Please help

Answer (score 0):

following code may help to delete all cookies:

```
 string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
        foreach (string cookie in cookies)
        {
            BulletedList1.Items.Add("Deleting " + cookie);
            Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }
```

or follow the way as below if want remove ore clear cookie after logged out:

```
HttpCookieCollection cookieCols= New HttpCookieCollection();
cookieCols = Request.Cookies;
Request.Cookies.Remove("PASS");
Request.Cookies.Remove("UID") ;
```

you may also write the statement as below in the logout event to clear cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: Hi, thank u i tried what you said and it did not work for me. When i executed the following it solved my issue runas /env /user:Adminuser \"cmd /K \"RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

Answer (score 0):

Just our luck, Selenium 2.34 and IEDriverServer just came out. Now you can easily start a clean browser (cookies deleted) in IE without hacking. See the comment in the blog post [here](http://automationoverflow.blogspot.in/2013/07/clean-session-in-internet-explorer.html). But now all you need is the code.

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions{EnsureCleanSession = true};
var ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```